# OpenJ9 performance not great?

Tags: openj9

Recently [renessaince.dev](https://renaissance.dev) published performance results from a large set of realistic tests (their words). OpenJ9 does not look good!

Are there any issues with OpenJ9 configuration the testers might have overlooked?

Comment: Can you please link the benchmark directly?
The only one I can find on the site compares OpenJDK to GraalVM.